# PDO not posting to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here's the code:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE muted_alerts SET `customer_id`=':customer_id', `sms_time` = '$fdate', `phone`=':phone'";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql1, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY) );
$stmt->execute(array(':phone' => $phone,':customer_id'=>$customer_id));
$result1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This throws no errors. I've used `var_dump` to see if `$phone`, `$fdate` and `$customer_id` are valid and they are.

I'm guessing there's a problem in my statement somehow. I excluded all the `$dbh` lines for simplicity, but I have tested and know these are correct also.

Comment: note: named placeholders need not to be quoted

Comment: @Ghost What about `$fdate`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from the fields and the colon in the keys of the array inside of the execute method. You dont need it.See below:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE muted_alerts SET customer_id=:customer_id, sms_time = :f_date, phone=:phone";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql1, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY) );
$stmt->execute(array('phone' => $phone,'f_date' => '$fdate','customer_id'=>$customer_id));
$result1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```